# Assigning NA using quotes or not in R

Tags: r, na, missing-data

I have some data where the missing values are not coded as NA and I would like to change them to NA to be handled automatically by an R package that imputes missing data.  The code I am using is this:

```
levels(data$catagorical_var)[levels(data$categorical_var) == "BLANK"] <- NA

data$numeric_var[data$numeric_var == -2] <- NA
```

My question is, for the categorical variable should I have quotes around NA? Does it matter? It gives me different results when I use quotes vs. without quotes and I am not sure which is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you should not use quotes. `NA` is R's missing value. `"NA"` is a character string with the letters "N" and "A" in it.

There are actually different types of `NA` (for each of R's data types). They are specified with underscores, e.g., `NA_integer_`, or `NA_character_`. But almost never need to use them, R will automatically use the right one. Your exact question is actually covered in the **Details** section of `?NA` (first paragraph):

> The `NA` of character type is distinct from the string `"NA"`. Programmers who need to specify an explicit missing string should use `NA_character_` (rather than `"NA"`) or set elements to `NA` using `is.na<-`.

Your code, `..character vector.. <- NA` falls under "*set elements to `NA` using `is.na<-`.*"